# Issue with enrolling a paid lesson free to student as an moodle admin

Tags: moodle

I have a course with multiple lessons with lesson2 having paypal enrollment.  As a admin I enrolled a student to this course. But when I logged in as a student, I am not able to attend lesson 2 since which shows "
Restricted Not available unless: you make a payment with PayPal". An admin cannot enroll a paid lesson to a student as free?

Answer (score 0):

> An admin cannot enroll a paid lesson to a student as free?

Unfortunately no.

As an admin what you can do is create a hidden activity called bypass. Make sure the activity is hidden from all student users. Then adjust the lesson2 restrictions to allow the users to access the activity if your "hidden" activity has been marked as completed.

This will basically allow you to bypass the normal paypal restriction.

Edit 1: I would also look at creating a 100% discount code that could perhaps be used. This will create some other use-case issues though that you will need to decide on how to handle.